# In which orientation should the dummy voltage source be connected when determining the i-v characteristics?

Tags: voltage

Suppose, I have a circuit like this:

[image]

Now, in order to find the i-v characteristics, I have to connect a variable voltage source across the A-B terminals. Now, this can be done in one of two ways. The two ways are given:

[image]

This is the first way. Let us figure out the equation for this case. In the closed loop PQRSP, we can apply KVL,

2I-V2+5=0

This can alternatively be written as 2y-x+5=0

We can also find out the equation without using KVL. The voltage drop across the resistor R1 is V2-V1 (assuming that the current I flows *from* V2 *to* V1). Then I=(V2-V1)/2. We will eventually get 2y-x+5=0 from here.

[image]

This is the second way. We can determine the equation using KVL. In the closed loop TMNOT,

-2I+V2+5=0

or, -2y+x+5=0

Also, we can determine the equation in an alternative way. The voltage drop across R1 is V1+V2 or 5+V2. Then I=(V1+V2)/2. Then, from that we can derive -2y+x+5=0.

Here V2 is the variable voltage source. Now, I have found that the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cqiwqiec7b) becomes different when I connect the variable voltage in the opposite orientation. The red line is for the first orientation, and the purple line is for the second orientation. I used KVL to find the equations. I initially expected both the graphs to be the same. I was unpleasantly surprised to find that that was not the case.

Now, say I was given the above circuit in my lab exam. How should I connect V2 to the circuit? In what orientation? I will get two different equations/graphs/i-v characteristics for the same circuit by connecting in two different orientations. How do I know which is the right one?

Comment: A current pointing out of the positive end is negative. In both your cases a current following your arrows will be negative since both your arrows point out of the positive end. Since I'd likely be interested in the blue arrow direction I'd use the orientation found in the green arrow case. This would not look like your red line, though, if the x axis is the voltage of V2. I don't know how you got your equation. V2=0 gives 2.5 A and V2=5 gives 0 A in your first schematic.

Comment: @periblepsis I edited my question to show how I got the equations. Should've done that  the first time. My bad.

Comment: Here's the [I/V curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rby2S.png). Simple. Does your equation reproduce this?

Comment: I've provided the complete schematic for LTspice that you can use. It provides the proper resulting load line (2 Ohm.) If you have ***any*** remaining questions, let me know.

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you so much!! I am just a bit run-down; that's why I couldn't get back to you earlier. The thing is that I was able to derive your equations too by taking current (I) out of the negative terminal (i.e. by considering the current coming out of the negative terminal to be positive, but I find that convention a bit strange). I mean it is fine, but I thought that the well-recognized convention was that the current coming out of the *positive terminal* is *positive*.

Comment: In Spice the convention is that current leaving the positive terminal of a voltage source is a negative value. This is so that when you multiply the voltage source's difference, positive to negative (which is always a positive value), by its current then it is absorbing power if the product is positive and delivering power if the product is negative. Think about a two-terminal resistor, for example, and you will see why this choice was made. Anyway, that's the way it is done in Spice. Other well-recognized conventions are free to differ. But Spice handles it this way.

Comment: @periblepsis Great! Okay, let me ask you the main question I have. I will try to be very clear. Suppose, I wake up tomorrow, and then go to school. There, my instructor gives me a black box. He tells me to find the i-v characteristics of the black box. The black box has two terminals **a** and **b**. Then, I fetch a variable voltage source from the lab assistant. Now, my question to you is that, in what orientation should I connect the voltage source to the terminals a and b? (continued)

Comment: @periblepsis (continued) If I connect the positive terminal to a, then I will get one graph, and if I connect the negative terminal to a, I will get another graph. The two graphs will be different. It doesn't make sense for one black box to have two *different* i-v characteristics graphs, does it?

Comment: You cannot perform the experiment you propose without a very special type of voltage supply. So special in fact that I don't own one. It must be capable of four quadrant operation and able to both deliver and absorb power. These are rare. If you find a good one, please consider donating it to me.

Comment: @periblepsis Say, I have one at my house. I bought it with 1 million dollars in cash from a suspicious stranger. I intend to give it to you after I finish the experiment. Now, in which orientation should I connect the voltage source?

Comment: In the usual way shown in the schematic I provided. However, what matters will be how the designer chooses to report the resulting current. They have two choices and will make a marketing decision based on what they think their customers prefer seeing.

Comment: You of course will have to be sufficiently knowledgeable to be able to properly interpret the results based upon the user manual and their specifications. I'll certainly be willing to help you there after I receive the unit and can verify my own understanding. ;)

Comment: I can also provide a schematic that would allow for a two quadrant current sink or source controlled by a voltage input. This could be used to interrogate the black box by sliding the current and measuring the voltage for a plot. That would be a lot cheaper. Or you could just apply a voltmeter and an ammeter. Even cheaper that way,, though you only get two points and not a curve.

Comment: @periblepsis Ah yes. I'm afraid I have some bad news. Upon the completion of the experiment, the unit went out of order. I still shipped the contraption yesterday; you may be able to fix it. However, the shipping agency that I chose is not very good. They take a long while to deliver goods. I had no other option, unfortunately. Hopefully, it will reach you on time, but if it doesn't, I'm afraid the agency mucked it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think your math isn't quite right

To be clear, you're trying to produce a graph that shows the current in the circuit, when an external voltage source is applied, where both V1 and V2 are assumed to be perfect sources, with no internal resistance, capable of sourcing or sinking infinite current. 
I might gently note that this seems a bit odd to me, perhaps this is a specific task you've been set.

As you understand, to get the current in this circuit, you must find the voltage drop across the resistor R1, which is (V1 - V2). Where the resistance is 2Ω, 
I = (V1-V2)/2, given that V1 is fixed at 5V, 
I = (5 - V2)/2
You could rearrange this to 2I + V2 - 5 = 0, and substitute I=Y and V2=X to get this into the format
2Y + X - 5 = 0
If we then reverse the polarity of V2, as in your second circuit, we then change the polarity of V2 in the math, giving
I = (V1 + V2)/2 or
2Y - X - 5 = 0

For both of these, we're getting a value for the current flowing where a positive value is the current flowing clockwise (or out of the positive terminal of V1), and a positive anti-clockwise. 
I see that in your first circuit, the arrow suggests a positive value for the current flowing anticlockwise. Where current flows in a circuit are absolute, but whether this is considered positive or negative depends on your perspective/math/measurement orientation. If we flip this, and consider an anticlockwise current positive for the first circuit we get 
I = (V2-V1)/2 or
2Y - X + 5 = 0

Assuming the change in polarity of the current between the two circuits is deliberate the two graphs should be
2Y - X - 5 = 0, where X is the value of V2, and Y represents the value of anticlockwise current. 
Then for the second circuit
2Y - X + 5 = 0, where X is the value of V2, and Y represents the value of clockwise current.
Because both the current and V2 change orientation together, there isn't a polarity shift in the two graphs.

[after significant edit to question]

For your first circuit, KVL 
2I - V2 + 5 = 0
This is wrong, 5V is generated by V1, this is opposed by V2 (so this is -V2), but the voltage droped accross R1 is also a negative, so your equation should be 
**-2I** - V2 +5 = 0 
I've rearranged this to hopefully make this clear. If it helps, consider if V2 wasn't there, then the equation would have to be 
5 - 2I = 0 
Of course, you can flip the polarity to go from 
-2I - V2 + 5 = 0 to
2I + V2 - 5 = 0. These are the same equation, in this case, you have an incorrect -2I

For the second circuit, now that you have flipped the polarity of V2, the equation becomes 
-2I + V2 + 5 = 0 or
2I - V2 - 5 = 0
Which is how you have it.

I still don't quite understand the exercise. If the point is to generate a graph of voltage and current out, a graph that says for a given voltage across QR, then this current must be drawn, then I'd go with the first. Technically they both produce the same relationship, it's just that the second reverses the polarity - ie this considers a voltage RQ, rather than QR. It's still the same value.

Comment: My second equation is exactly the same as your second equation.

Comment: I edited my question to show how I got the equations. Should've done that  the first time. My bad.